# TinyMCE adds a &nbsp; after a HR

Tags: tinymce

I noticed that TinyMCE adds a non-breaking space after a horizontal rule element, this isn't required and adds additional space to my layout if there isn't any content after the `<hr/>`

I've tried configuring TinyMCE via functions.php but nothing prevents the nbsp being added:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', mce_mod( $init ) {
    $init["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;
    return $init;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't far from the answer:

```
function mce_mod( $init ) {
  $init['apply_source_formatting'] = false;
  return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod', 99);
```

add this to functions.php and it will stop the nbsp's.

[From the TinyMCE docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:apply_source_formatting)

if you want to fully tame tinyMCE I recommend you check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sidonaldson/67268666c5501f06289d)